# jQuery datatables vertical scroll bug with fixed column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

Ok i have noticed this bug with FireFox and IE 11 how to replicate it:

- Start scrolling on the fixed column
- While its scrolling move the mouse over to the other data
- Result: not aligned rows

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nniicc/pkbmabeo/)

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'ignore';
$('#myTable01').DataTable( {
    scrollY:        "200px",
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false,
    fixedColumns:   true,
    bPaginate: false,
    bFilter: false,
    bInfo: false,
    bSort: false,

} );
```

[image]

Is there a way to fix this in FireFox and IE? I have tried chrome and it works fine there.

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Comment: Never was able to fix it so pretty much just ignored it

Answer (score 1):

file: dataTables.fixedColumns.js

Delete row: iBodyweight -= oOverflow.bar;

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response. 
I am also faced similar issue. Given the fix below. Please try & let me know,if any challenges.

File: dataTables.fixedColumns.js 
Version : 3.2.4

Update below condition in "scroll.DTFC" Event

Existing Code:  `

```
 if (mouseController === 'main') {
        if (that.s.iLeftColumns > 0) {
      that.dom.grid.left.liner.scrollTop = that.dom.scroller.scrollTop;
 }
  if (that.s.iRightColumns > 0) {
                                                                that.dom.grid.right.liner.scrollTop = that.dom.scroller.scrollTop;
 }`

Updated Code : ` if (mouseController === 'main'|| mouseController === 'left') {
if (that.s.iLeftColumns > 0) {
                                                                that.dom.grid.left.liner.scrollTop = that.dom.scroller.scrollTop;
  }
 if (that.s.iRightColumns > 0) {
                        that.dom.grid.right.liner.scrollTop = that.dom.scroller.scrollTop;
                                                            }
 }
```

`